# R studio Error unexpected numeric constant

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a sleep study table. Long list of data. For some reason the reaction data will not enter.

```
Reaction<-c(249.56,249.56,258.7047,250.8006,321.4398,356.8519,414.6901,382.2038,
290.146,430.5853,466.3535,22.7339,205.2658,202.9778,204.7070,207.7161,
215.9618,213.6303,217.7272,224.2957,237.3142,199.0539,194.3322,
234.32,232.8416,229.3074220.4579235.4208,255.7511,261.0125,247.5153,
321.5426,300.4002,283.8565,285.133,285.7973,297.5855,280.2396,318.2613,
305.3495,354.0487,287.6079,285,301.8206,320.1153,316.2773,293.3187,
290.075.334.8177,293.746,371.5811,234.8606,242.8118,272.9613,309.7688,
317.4629,309.9976,454.1619,346.8311,330.3003,253.8644,283.8424,289.555,
276.7693,299.8097,297.171,338.1665,332.0265,348.8399,333.36,362.0428,
265.4731,276.2012,243.3647,254.6723,279.0244,284.1912,305.5248,331.5229,
335.7469,377.299,241.6083,273.9472,254.4907,270.8021,251.4519,254.6362,
245.4523,235.311,235.7541,237.2466,312.3666,313.8058,291.6112,346.1222,
365.7324,391.8385,404.2601,416.6923,455.8643,458.9167,236.1032,230.3167,
238.9256,254.922,250.7103,269.7744,281.5648,308.102,336.2806,351.6451,
256.2968,243.4543,256.2046,255.5271,268.9165,329.7247,379.4445,
362.9184,394.4872,389.0527,250.5265,300.0576,269.8939,280.5891,
271.8274,304.6336,287.7466,266.5955,321.5418,347.5655,221.6771,
298.1939,326.8785,346.8555,348.7402,352.8287,354.4266,360.4326,
375.6406,388.5417,271.9235,268.4369,257.2424,277.6566,314.8222,
317.2135,298.1353,348.1229,340.28,366.5131,225.264,234.5235,238.9008,
240.473,267.5373,344.1937,281.1481,347.5855,365.163,372.2288,269.8804,
272.4428,277.8989,281.7895,279.1705,284.512,259.2658,304.6306,350.7807,
369.4692,269.4117,273.474,297.5968,310.6316,287.1726,329.6076,
334.4818,343.2199,369.1417,364.1236)
```

> Error: *unexpected numeric constant in
>   "Reaction<-c(249.56,249.56,258.7047,250.8006,321.4398,356.8519,414.6901,382.2038,290.146,430.5853,466.3535,22.7339,205.2658,202.9778,204.7070,207.7161,215.9618,213.6303,217.7272,224.2957,237.31"*

The table has number, days, reaction & subject. I can enter all the other rows except the reaction row.

Comment: there is an entry with "229.3074220.4579235", this is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

"229.3074220.4579235.4208"

--
is your problem.

Comment: You can use the RStudio function Find/Replace (Ctrl + f) to find the error in the vector